# socket.connect throwing a TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to connect to a port on a server using socket.connect() - and I'm passing a tuple to this function with the IP addr and the port. This is per standard here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket

```
[som@jsclone pwman]$ cat test.py 
#!/home/som/dev/dev/bin/python
import socket


def open_socket(port, ip='127.0.0.1'):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    return s


sock = open_socket(49152)
```

When I try to execute the code above, I get the error:

```
[som@jsclone pwman]$ ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    sock = open_socket(49152)
  File "./test.py", line 7, in open_socket
    s.connect((ip, port))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

Python version:

```
[som@jsclone pwman]$ /home/som/dev/dev/bin/python --version
Python 3.7.4
```

As you can see, simply connecing to the port (without even actually sending any data I'm getting this error! I'm aware of this case, [where `socket.sendall()` throws this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344818/socket-sendall-method-throws-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not), but not `socket.connect()`!

What am I doing wrong?
P.S. I can't use `socket.sendto()` due to the nature of some other dependent code.

Comment: Did you mean to use socket `AF_INET` instead of `AF_UNIX`? Unix sockets are local files and they do not have ports or IP addresses. That's why it's expecting bytes instead of a tuple.

Comment: @jordanm that was exactly it! 

Thank you so much man!

Comment: @jordanm can you please resubmit as an answer instead of a comment? your explanation is a lot better than Naga's (who just gave a keyword and a link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it is not working for you is that you wrote `AF_UNIX` instead of `AF_INET`.
UNIX - sockets for local interprocess communication. Instead of identifying a server by an IP address and port, a UNIX domain socket is known by a pathname.

Try this code:

```
import socket


def open_socket(port, ip='127.0.0.1'):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    return s


sock = open_socket(49152)
```

If you are interested to read more about UNIX sockets you can read this: https://troydhanson.github.io/network/Unix_domain_sockets.html

Answer (score 1):

socket.AF_INET

```
import socket


def open_socket(port, ip='127.0.0.1'):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    return s


sock = open_socket(49152)
```

https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: Can you please edit the answer to have more context? That's the right answer, but it should be explained a bit -- like jordanm did in the comment for my question. 
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer